# cURL with the real server IP while using CloudFlare

Tags: curl, ip, cloudflare

Our partners have whitelisted our server IP so we can send them cURL requests with new client data but their CRM returns `Error: IP address of a connected platform is not allowed` probably because the headers contain a CloudFlare IP rather than the real IP of our server which we asked to whitelist.

Is there a way to reveal our real server IP with a cURL request?

```
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://clients.domain.com/api');

            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);


            $res = curl_exec($curl);
            return $res;
```

Tried this with no success:

```
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, '1.1.1.1');
```

And:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("REMOTE_ADDR: 1.1.1.1, HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: 1.1.1.1"));
```

EDIT: their logs show an IPv6 IP instead of the IPv4 server IP and it looks like this: `2a02:7aa0:1201::xxxx:xxxx`after some investigation it appears that this IPv6 IP is hosted by out hosting company and after whitelisting it everything started working.
Any thoughts on why cURL send out some strange IPv6 instead of real server IPv4?

Comment: CloudFlare is an inbound proxy so outgoing cURL requests do not go through CloudFlare and will appear from your server's public IP.  Try curling a site that shows your IP address and see if that matches what you gave them.

Comment: Are there any public sites to help me with that or I need to make a script on my own?

Comment: Used https://ifconfig.co/ and it shows the server IP. Very strange, how is it possible that it works on localhost and not working on the server (both IPs are whitelisted)

Comment: Unsure why it works locally and not on the server when both IPS are white listed. So for sure this server IP that showed when curling ifconfig.co is the one that's white listed and we're sure it got added properly? Might check with the company and have them tell you what IP they see from the server that's being denied. I don't think your server or the code is the problem, and just to reiterate, clouldflare and outbound curl requests are unrelated and curl would in no way go through them.

Comment: @drew010 It now shows a strange IPv6 in their logs: 2a02:7aa0:1201::XXXX:XXXX. After a quick whois check - it's the IP of our server. Any thought on why it sends an IPv6 instead of IPv4?

Comment: Modern Linux and windows will use ipv6 first if you and the remote server have it. You can set the curl option CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE to CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 to force IPv4 and that should solve your problem. You might want to have them add the v6 address too in case it ever falls back to that due to issues.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You bet!  Hope that helped and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

yeah well, if `clients.domain.com` is going through CF's proxy, then you could  connect directly to the server, and probably just fake the host header. as of PHP 7.0.7, this can be done as

`curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
CURLOPT_URL=>'http://clients.domain.com/api',//to set the host 
CURLOPT_CONNECT_TO=>'::8.8.8.8:80'
));`

- but replace `:80`  with `:443` if you're connecting with httpS

and replace `8.8.8.8`  with the real server's IP (not the cloudflare IP)

or if you're not on PHP 7.0.7+ yet, in older versions, you can do

`curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
CURLOPT_URL=>'http://8.8.8.8/api',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>array('Host: clients.domain.com')
));`

(again, replace `8.8.8.8` with the real server's IP, not the cloudflare IP)
to set the host header manually. im not sure that will work properly with http Location redirects and CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, though, so you might have to handle Location http redirects manually